# Is formula can extract long space date from text string?

Tags: excel

i have do the research all over the internet but most of the references is about dd/mm/yy or dd.mm.yy but i want something like dd mmmm yyyy (between are using space)

and i have tried to used

```
=MID(A1,SEARCH("?? ????? ????",A1),13)
```

to extract the date from the text string but it will error in some cell such as display the text not date.

my date will be in 2 type below:

on (1 April 2020)

on 1 April 2020

Comment: the problem is that `?? ????? ????` assumes a two digit day and a 5 character month which most do not fall into.  You will not find a pattern that works here.

Answer (score 0):

if on has CONCAT and FILTERXML:

```
=CONCAT(IFERROR(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,")",""),"(","")," ","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b[starts-with(following::*[1],"&{"'Jan'","'Feb'","'Mar'","'Apr'","'May'","'Jun'","'Jul'","'Aug'","'Sep'","'Oct'","'Nov'","'Dec'"}&")]"),""))&" "&CONCAT(IFERROR(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,")",""),"(","")," ","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b[starts-with(.,"&{"'Jan'","'Feb'","'Mar'","'Apr'","'May'","'Jun'","'Jul'","'Aug'","'Sep'","'Oct'","'Nov'","'Dec'"}&")]"),""))&" "&CONCAT(IFERROR(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,")",""),"(","")," ","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b[starts-with(preceding::*[1],"&{"'Jan'","'Feb'","'Mar'","'Apr'","'May'","'Jun'","'Jul'","'Aug'","'Sep'","'Oct'","'Nov'","'Dec'"}&")]"),""))
```

[image]

Note: this returns the string.  If one wants a true date then:

```
=--(CONCAT(IFERROR(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,")",""),"(","")," ","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b[starts-with(following::*[1],"&{"'Jan'","'Feb'","'Mar'","'Apr'","'May'","'Jun'","'Jul'","'Aug'","'Sep'","'Oct'","'Nov'","'Dec'"}&")]"),""))&" "&CONCAT(IFERROR(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,")",""),"(","")," ","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b[starts-with(.,"&{"'Jan'","'Feb'","'Mar'","'Apr'","'May'","'Jun'","'Jul'","'Aug'","'Sep'","'Oct'","'Nov'","'Dec'"}&")]"),""))&" "&CONCAT(IFERROR(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,")",""),"(","")," ","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b[starts-with(preceding::*[1],"&{"'Jan'","'Feb'","'Mar'","'Apr'","'May'","'Jun'","'Jul'","'Aug'","'Sep'","'Oct'","'Nov'","'Dec'"}&")]"),"")))
```

And format the date as desired.